# No jansi in library.path

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I have a Scala.js web application according to [this example](https://github.com/lihaoyi/workbench-example-app/tree/autowire) and I am trying to call a 3rd party Java library.

I get a strange error indicating that a jansi lib is missing, but I added *jansi-1.11.jar* to my path.

```
    exampleJVM [INFO] [02/16/2016 16:14:56.331] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://default/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0] Bound to /0.0.0.0:8080
    exampleJVM[ERROR] Uncaught error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[default]
    exampleJVM [ERROR] [02/16/2016 16:14:58.694] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [ActorSystem(default)] Uncaught error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting
     down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
    exampleJVM[ERROR] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi in java.library.path]
    exampleJVM[ERROR]       at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.doLoad(Library.java:182)
    exampleJVM java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi in java.library.path]
    exampleJVM[ERROR]       at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.load(Library.java:140)
    exampleJVM[ERROR]       at org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32.<clinit>(Kernel32.java:37)
    exampleJVM      at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.doLoad(Library.java:182)
    exampleJVM[ERROR]       at org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream.<clinit>(WindowsAnsiOutputStream.java:52)
    exampleJVM[ERROR]       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    exampleJVM      at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.load(Library.java:140)
    exampleJVM[ERROR]       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    exampleJVM      at org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32.<clinit>(Kernel32.java:37)
    exampleJVM[ERROR]       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    exampleJVM      at org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream.<clinit>(WindowsAnsiOutputStream.java:52)
    exampleJVM[ERROR]       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    exampleJVM      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    exampleJVM[ERROR]       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender.getOutputStream(ConsoleAppender.java:198)
    exampleJVM      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

I tried several things that were proposed somewhere... I installed Visual Studio C++ Redistributables or added `fork in run := true` to my *build.sbt* - but no success...

Comment: This one really doesn't have anything to do with scala.js, since it's a server-side library.  You might want to try asking on the akka/akka Gitter community...

Comment: Could you please explain how you added jansi-1.11.jar to your path?

Comment: I added it to my build.sbt like expert suggested. Furthermore I added it to the Buildpath of my eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
"org.fusesource.jansi" % "jansi" % "1.11",
```

to line 29 of your `build.sbt`

https://github.com/lihaoyi/workbench-example-app/blob/autowire/build.sbt#L29

**UPDATE**:  I downloaded your project (branch `autowire`), added dependency to `build.sbt` and added following lines to `example.Server.main`:

```
import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole
import org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi._
import org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.Color._

AnsiConsole.systemInstall()
println( ansi().eraseScreen().fg(RED).a("Hello").fg(GREEN).a(" World").reset() )
```

it works for me. Could you upload your version of code to github?

Comment: I updated the answer. I think there is something in your version of the code.

Comment: Hm, I added your code and "Hello World" is printed on the console. However, when I call an external (Java)Library the same error message appears. In the external lib the error is caused by `org.apache.logging.log4j`. Does the external library look for jansi in a different libpath?

Comment: @KlausSchulz How do you call external library ?

Comment: I put the jar-file in my lib-directory and import the relevant classes to my .scala codefile.

Comment: @KlausSchulz Hmm. Well, put your entire project to git. I'll take a look.

Comment: Unfortunatly this project is quite large and legal issues prohibit me to put it in a public place like github. :-( However, I could publish some pieces that are relevant for the question. I know that this is poking around in fog....

Comment: I'd recommend building stripped version of the project. Often when I do that I find problem myself :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is a runtime error. So, I think you've nothing to do with the build path. If you're working in Windows, try installing jansi.dll into any of the java.library.path directories; such as c:/windows/system32. I suppose this is not the best way to solve but it worked fine for me after dealing 3 hours to find a way to alter the runtime path to include jansi.jar file.